# Number formatting in pivot table with Aspose.Cells

Tags: aspose

I am creating a pivot table in excel sheet by aspose.cells. I want the values to be formatted as Accounting, with a symbol, a comma and 2 decimal places. Is this possible with aspose.cells? Please suggest how to do this with Aspose.Cells and c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need Accounting number formatting for the PivotField, you may try to use the following numeric formatting using PivotField.Number attribute instead.

```
pivotTable.DataFields[0].Number = 43; //You may also try it with 44 if it suits your needs.
```

Alternatively you may try to use the following formatting string for NumberFormat custom attribute of PivotField. You may also check in MS Excel to get your desired custom strings to try with NumberFormat property.

```
_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

If you still face any confusion/issue, can you please share the sample Excel file in which you may manually set the desired number formatting for the Pivot Table fields in MS Excel, and share the file with us, so that we can test the scenario at our end.

Furthermore, can you please share the code/sample application with the template files (input, output and expected output file etc.). The files can also be shared in [Aspose.Cells product support forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much codewarior! I have been struggling with this from so many days. I cannot add the number but i have set the custom property and it is working perfectly. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using PivotField.NumberFormat property to specify his desired formatting, see the code segment below for reference:

```
//Specify the number formatting to the first data field added.
pivotTable.DataFields[0].NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00";
```

Moreover, we also recommend you use our latest version of [Aspose.Cells for .NET 7.4.0](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/entry439948.aspx) in which we made some more enhancements regarding PivotTables.

*PS, I am working as Support developer / Technical Evangelist at Aspose.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this doesn't solve my problem. I already have this format defined but you know when i create excel sheet it says "Custom" when any number is selected and that is fine but in accounting format if there is no number it shows "-" in the cell which is not possible with this format. Any suggestions would be appreciated.